# Template specialization for two types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a static member function `lerp()` inside my class template `AnimCurve` which I want to specialize for Quaternions, this way:

```
template<>
inline Quatf AnimCurve<Quatf>::lerp( 
    const Quatf& start, 
    const Quatf& end, 
    float time 
    )
{
    return start.slerp(time, end);
}
```

However, this is not generic enough because one may also use `Quatd`. Is it possible to write a function which would work for both, since both `Quatf` and `Quatd` are type definitions of `Quaternion<T>`?

Here is the current definition of `AnimCurve`:

```
template< typename T >
class AnimCurve {
public:
    AnimCurve() {}
    void addKeyframe(float time, T value);
    T getvalue(float time) const;
private:
    static inline T lerp( const T& start, const T& end, float time );
    std::map<float, T> mKeyframes;
};
```

Comment: You say that you have a "generic lerp function", but your code seems to indicate that it is in fact the class `AnimCurve` which is a template. Could you confirm this (perhaps by posting the declaration of `lerp`)?

Comment: Another question, just to be sure: do you want your specialization to be used for *all* `Quaternion`s, or just `Quatf` and `Quatd`?

Comment: @LucTouraille Just both. Also, the class AnimCurve is indeed a template, the declaration of my lerp function is in the first line of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a function which would work for both, since both Quatf and Quatd are type definitions of Quaternion?

If you want to specialize your `lerp` algorithm for *exactly* those two instantiations of the `Quaternion` class template, and no other instantiations, then no, you have to explicitly specialize both of them: once for `AnimCurve<Quatf>` and once for `AnimCurve<Quatd>`.

Comment: I can see both `Quaternion<Q>` and `Quatf` which confused me!

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, now that I look at it, it's unclear whether this is a function template or a member function of a class template. Will need to clarify that

Comment: It's a member function, part of an AnimCurve class.

Comment: @num3ric: Could you then post the definition of `AnmiCurve`?